# Error message with RegionPlot after SetOptions

Tags: bugs, options, plotting

I get an error message with

```
SetOptions[RegionPlot, ImageSize ->  Medium];
RegionPlot[u v (1 - v) >= 10, {v, 0, 1}, {u, 0, 100}]
```

that says

```
Join::heads: Heads List and Rule at positions 1 and 2 are expected to be the same. >>
```

That message does not occur without the SetOptions line. Any clue as to what is going on ? (This happens in 9.0.0 and 9.0.1 Mac).

Comment: I get the proper plot and no error message using v. 10.0.0.

Comment: Same here with 10.0.2.0

Comment: Confirm same error on v9 for win32

Comment: Thanks to all, I reported this as a bug. Dunno if Wolfram will update 9.0.1 though.

Comment: It seems this bug is resolved with MMA >=10.0? @Mr.Wizard